# What is the meaning of malloc, realloc, calloc? I want to know full name of these functions

Tags: c

I have tried to find it in google, but I couldn't.
I am studying C.
And now my stage is pointer and function about management memory.
But malloc, realloc, calloc...etc are hard to memorize.
So I want to know the full context. It will help to remember their meaning.
I do not speak English well. So my writing may be weird.
Please understand. Thanks for reading.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/#:~:text=%E2%80%9Crealloc%E2%80%9D%20or%20%E2%80%9Cre-allocation%E2%80%9D%20method%20in%20C%20is%20used,realloc%20can%20be%20used%20to%20dynamically%20re-allocate%20memory. try this

Comment: The functon `malloc` probably stands for "memory allocate".  The function `realloc` probably stands for "(memory) reallocate". I have no idea what `calloc` stands for, though.

Comment: Please read [any of the already available references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) on the internet.

Comment: `calloc` "clear allocate". Notable by its absence is `crealloc()`. If as a non-native speaker of English you find them hard to memorise, the key part is "alloc" part of the verb "allocate".

Comment: @WeatherVane Some sources like [this](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation) say `calloc()` stands for "contiguous allocate" but TBH "clear allocate" better describes its purpose.

Comment: @AmalK all memory allocations are contiguous, so that doesn't adequately describe the difference between `malloc` and `calloc`, which is a stated in your link. "The `malloc()` function allocates memory and leaves the memory uninitialized. Whereas, the `calloc()` function allocates memory and initializes all bits to zero."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**M**emory **Alloc**ation (and reallocation etc...)

There is an awful lot to say about these functions but check out [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/) for a start.

And if you can still buy it read "The C Programming Language" by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Richie. A **MUST** Read